# How can I make a div stand right above another element (the element below it)?

Tags: html, css, margin

I want the two buttons "Upload File" and "New Catalog" stand right above the text "Catalog path: Main", but stay in the right side of the search form (like it looks like in the picture).

[image]

Putting a "margin top: 11em" or something like that does make the buttons move below (this is what I have done currently). But this doesn't make website look better: when you add a lot of tags on the search form the buttons are on the same place. Or when you resize the window the buttons keep a "too much distance" from search.

These two buttons are placed inside a <div id="upload-buttons>. In HTML file that comes after <div class="search"> which is the search table standing at the right side. Right after "upload-buttons" comes <div class="overview>. Both "upload-buttons" and "search" are placed in <div id="container>.

This is what I have written in the HTML code (it's a Twig template, but that's not that different from HTML):

```
          <div id="container">
          <div class="search">
{#              <p>Today's date is: {{ object.date|date("Y-m-d") }}</p>#}
      <table id="search-form">
              <form method = "get">
                  <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
                  <label>Search in file database </label>
              </th>
              <th colspan="2">
                  <label>Search by tags</label>
              </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                  <br><input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search" maxlength="45">
                 <br><button type="submit" name="search" value="search">Search</button>
              </td>
              <td>
                      <label for="start">Start date range:</label>
                      <br><input type="date" id="from date" name="from-date"
                                 value=""
                                 min="2020-03-01" max="">
                  <br><label for="end">End date range:</label>
                  <br><input type="date" id="to date" name="to-date"
                             value=""
                             min="2020-03-01" max="">
              </td>
                      <td>
                      </td>
              </form>
              <form method = "get">
                  <td>
                      <br><input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="tag1,tag2,tag3">
                      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                      <script src="{{ rel }}js/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
                      <br><button type="submit" name="search" value="tagssearch">Search</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="andcondition" value="1">
                  Check if you want each file to include all tags (AND condition)
                  </td>
                  </tr>
              </form>
          </table>
              </div>
              <div id="upload-buttons">
                  <a href="{{rel}}file-upload/" class="button-white">Upload File</a>
                  <a href="{{rel}}new-catalog/" class="button-white">New Catalog</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="overview">

              <a id="catalogpath">
                  Catalog path: {{ catalogPath }}
              </a>
```

And this is what I have written in CSS:

```
    #container {
        position: relative;
    }

search {
    float: right;
    width: 45em;
    height: fit-content;
    background: midnightblue;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

#search-form table {
    vertical-align: top;
}


    #search-form td, #search-form tr, #search-form th{
        border-left: solid 0.5em transparent;
        border-right: solid 0.5em transparent;
    }

    /*FILES AND OVERVIEW*/

    #upload-buttons {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 11em;
    }

    .overview {
        clear: both;
    }



    #catalogpath {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: gold;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

I have tried: to put "upload-buttons" inside "overview". It then appears right above the catalog path, but then they don't stay on the left side of the search forms.

I have tried vertical-alignment and vertical-align attributes on "upload-buttons" and "container" but they still stay on the same place.

**How can I make the buttons stay right above (or almost right above the "catalog Path") but right side of the search forms without giving the button too big margin from any element above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make them `position: absolute` and write specific pixels from the top and left.

```
position: absolute; 
top: ___px; 
left: ___px;
```

I hope this helps.